SQL Server connection is getting established and not disposed through ADO.NET / C#
I am using the code shown here, to connect to SQL Server. This is working properly, but for the past 2 days, I am facing an issue where multiple connections (~2000) are getting opened and not getting disposed. Due to this, the CPU utilization is reaching 100% and system is unable to process any request.
Kindly help and suggest if I am doing anything wrong or any way to fix this.
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

try
{
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

    using (var command = _dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = "usp_get_userdetails";
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        if (_dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection().State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            _dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection().Open();
        }

        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserId", userid));

        var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter { SelectCommand = (SqlCommand)command };
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);

        dataTable = dataSet.Tables[0];
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}

return dataTable;

My connection string looks like this:
server=*******;uid=username;pwd=********;database= DBName;connection timeout=0;
    Max Pool Size = 1000;Pooling = True;TrustServerCertificate=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True


Unrelated, but don't do this: throw ex;  When re-throwing the same exception, just use throw;.  Currently the code is over-writing stack trace information about the exception.  (Or just remove the try/catch entirely if it's not actually handling the error.)

You're using a using for your command, but what about your connection? The fact you are checking to see if the connection state is open suggested not, so why not? If you did, the connections would be automatically disposed of. There's nothing in the close that does dispose of the connection, so why would you expect it to be? What code are you using to dispose your connection?

Why are you trying to use ADO.NET like this when you already use EF ? Why not use eg SqlQuery? High CPU is probably caused by too frequent garbage collection caused by data leaks. Leaked connections cause blocking in the database, not high CPU on the client

using (var command = _dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand()) this is very weird. What does GetDbConnection perform?

We are creating connection like below in Program.cs
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataAccessLayer.Contexts.DbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionstring));
@ThomA

GetDbConnection returns the one created and used by the DbContext instance during its lifetime and CreateCommand does create new DbCommand object .
@siggemannen

I might be doing wrong hence need expert advice to fix this issue.

Usually, you don't want to have one connection per app, what happens when you multithread? Although, sounds like you're leaking connections, so probably it's not a singleton :) You should create connections when you need them and then release back to the Pool using "using".

Exactly, I am not looking to have a single connection throughout the app lifecycle instead we want to create the connection and get it disposed once used. And we should have a pool from where it refers the connection. Kindly help @siggemannen

The critical thing here is the lifetime of the connection, and we can't see that from here - unless GetConnection() is returning a new connection each time, in which case: capture the result of GetConnection() and make sure it gets disposed (typically via using); if GetConnection() doesn't return a new connection each time, then: you need to find out how the connection lifetime is meant to work in that specific code

The outer using command needs to create a new instance of the connection object based on the connection string.  Inside of that using, then create your command object as you have.

@AlbertD.Kallal ok. so shall I use it like below. Is it correct?
using var connection = _odsDbContext.Database.GetDbConnection();
            using var command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "usp_get_userdetails";
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserId", userid));
            await connection.OpenAsync();


see my answer I posted. You are to use the connection string for the database, and create the connection. You THEN create a sqlcommand object (again in a using block) and that can/will use the conneciton object you created. And since  your returning ONLY a table, it makes no sense to pick/choose a dataset when you only want/have one table of data being returned. A dataset object is a collection of tables, and you only have/want one table, hence use a datatable object. And note how the command object has a reader, so no reader or data adaptor object is required either here.

you are opening connection manually and not closing or disposing it and because of that you are facing this issue. as old connection is not closing and new one are getting created because of that connection pool is exhausting. Always close the database connections when finished, to allow the connection to return to the pool a promising idea is to make use of the “using” statement in your database connection code blocks.

you could refer this document for more detail about how to manage connection: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/ and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling

As I pointed out in comments, the older dataset designer is in fact a ORM, and is the precursor to EF. And the dataset designer even provides strong typed tables (of which the poster is not using).
The simple matter, when writing such custom code, then you need/want to create a instance of the connection object in your outer using block. Then inside, another one for the command object should be created.
Hence, your code will wind up like this:
DataTable mytable = new DataTable();

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_get_userdetails", conn))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        conn.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserId", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value =  userid;
        mytable.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());  
    }
}

As a FYI:
You want to STRONG type the parameter, and hence if userid is a int, then you use this:
cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserId", SqlDbType.Int).Value =  userid;

You have to replace the connection string I used above with a valid connection string.
Note how we do NOT check if the connection is open, and note how we NEVER (do not) close the connection. The "using" blocks will correctly handle the closing and disposing of the connection object. And even better, .NET will automatically "pool" the connection and re-use it for reasons of performance.

You don't say the type of dbContext, but unless it's doing something strange, it is getting a new connection from the connection pool every time you call GetDbConnection. You need to get the connection once, attach the command to it, then dispose it afterwards.
    using (var connection = _dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection())
    {
        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "usp_get_userdetails";
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                connection.Open();
            }

            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserId", userid));

            var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter { SelectCommand = (SqlCommand)command };
            dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);

            dataTable = dataSet.Tables[0];
        }
    }


only suggesting here is I would strong type the parameter. See my example as to how I did this. And use of .add() is not depreciated as oh so many suggest, what is depreciated is using the overloaded .add where the int setting can be confused with the length setting (3 values).  Using 2 values for the .add() of the command object is still the recommended approach since you get strong type casting and checking.  Hence, you don't need the "new" sqlparameter, but using .add is just fine.

Avoid using DataSet, I recommend using Entity Framework and/or some ORM for connections, for example NPoco.
https://github.com/schotime/NPoco
https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/ef/

They are using a ORM - just the older one, and the poster is clearly using the dataset designer, which by ANY standards is a ORM.  The issue is they are using the connection object of that ORM, and THEN writing custom code - of which I pointed out means they need to create a new connection object on the "outer" using command, and then inside of that using, then they are to create a using block for the command object. On the other hand, if you offering to rewrite and re code their existing application, then by all means offer to do this for free, else someone going to have to pay for this!
